# How to convert between Json and Map<String, AttributeValue> in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I want to save an object that is encoded as a Json string to DynamoDB using the AWS Java SDK 2.0.

In the AWS Java SDK 1.n, it is possible to convert standard Json strings to DynamoDB `AttributeValues` using `Item.fromJSON(myJsonString).toAttributeValues()`.

Though it is possible to use both SDKs at once, the `AttributeValue` defined by the two SDK versions ([1.11](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/AttributeValue.html), [2.0](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/dynamodb/model/AttributeValue.html)) are not the same and cannot be used interchangeably.

Is there any AWS-provided or community-standard way to go from a json string/blob to a `Map<String, AttributeValue>` for the AWS Java SDK 2.0?

---

*Please note—this question is asking about how to solve the problem for **AWS Java SDK 2.0**, not the dynamodbv2 model of AWS Java SDK 1.n. If you think this question is a duplicate, please double check the SDK version of the question/answer that it duplicates.*

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: My data model was fairly small, so I hand-wrote my own converter directly from my data model to AttributeValues.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bit of a pain, but this should work for people:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.AttributeValue;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class DdbUtils {
    private static final ItemParameterizedType ITEM_PARAMETERIZED_TYPE = new ItemParameterizedType();
    private static final TypeReference<Map<String, AttributeValue.Builder>> ITEM_TYPEREF = new TypeReference<>() {
        @Override
        public Type getType() {
            return ITEM_PARAMETERIZED_TYPE;
        }
    };
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public DdbUtils() {
        // This is necessary because the fields are commonly "S" or "N", but the AttributeValue builder class
        // expects "s" and "n".
        this(new ObjectMapper().configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true));
    }

    public DdbUtils(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = Objects.requireNonNull(objectMapper);
    }

    public Map<String, AttributeValue> readItem(String string) throws IOException {
        return buildItemMap(objectMapper.readValue(string, ITEM_TYPEREF));
    }

    public Map<String, AttributeValue> readItem(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        return buildItemMap(objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, ITEM_TYPEREF));
    }

    public Map<String, AttributeValue> convertItem(Object object) {
        return buildItemMap(objectMapper.convertValue(object, ITEM_TYPEREF));
    }

    // ObjectMapper has a lot of methods; feel free to create more *Item methods right here.

    private Map<String, AttributeValue> buildItemMap(Map<String, AttributeValue.Builder> map) {
        return map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                entry -> entry.getValue().build()
            ));
    }

    // Map<String, AttributeValue.Builder>
    private static class ItemParameterizedType implements ParameterizedType {
        @Override
        public Type getRawType() {
            return Map.class;
        }

        @Override
        public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
            return new Type[] { String.class, AttributeValue.serializableBuilderClass() };
        }

        @Override
        public Type getOwnerType() {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
DdbUtils ddbUtils = new DdbUtils();
Map<String, AttributeValue> item = ddbUtils.readItem(/* whatever */);
```

Using AWS Java SDK v2, Jackson 2.12, and Java 17.

Answer (score -1):

An example for converting JSON to AttributeValue of DynamoDB

```
    String productString = readFileFromResources("data/categoryFix.json");
    HashMap<String,Object> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(productString, HashMap.class);
    Map<String, AttributeValue> attributes = InternalUtils.fromSimpleMap(result);
```

Above code worked well, even though InternalUtils is deprecated.

Comment: This answer is not for SDK 2 as requested.

Answer (score -1):

The `InternalUtils` is deprecated but the code below works fine and also shows, how you can convert that to `PutItemResult`:

```
HashMap responseMap = objectMapper.readValue(responseBody, HashMap.class);
            Map<String, AttributeValue> attributes = InternalUtils.fromSimpleMap(responseMap);

            PutItemResult result = new PutItemResult();
            result.setAttributes(attributes);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are a couple ways to do this (in Kotlin) depending on whether you have simple JSON or the DynamoDB json:

```kotlin
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.ItemUtils
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference

...
val objectMapper = ObjectMapper().apply {
    configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true)
}

...

// Method 1 - simple JSON
val obj1: MutableMap<String, AttributeValue> = ItemUtils.fromSimpleMap(
    objectMapper.readValue(
        """
                {
                 "fruits": ["apple", "pear"],
                 "user": { "name": "Bob" }
                }
            """,
        object : TypeReference<Map<String, Any>>() {})
)

// Method 2 - DynamoDB JSON
val obj2: Map<String, AttributeValue> =
    objectMapper.readValue("""
        {
         "fruits": {
          "L": [
             { 
              "S": "apple"
             },
             { 
              "S": "pear"
             }
          ]
         },
         "user": {
            "M": {
             "name": {
              "S": "Bob"
             }
            }
           }
        }
    """.trimIndent(),
    object : TypeReference<Map<String, AttributeValue>>() {}
)
```